# bokeh pass slider layout to components

Tags: django, bokeh

I'm using bokeh components to get script, div and pass to template

```
script, div = components(p)

return render(request, 'index.html', {"the_script": script, "the_div": div})
```

I'm trying to add date slider something like

```
date_range_slider = DateRangeSlider(title="Date Range: ", start=date(2017, 1, 1), end=date.today(), value=(date(2017, 9, 7), date(2017, 10, 15)), step=1)
layout = row(p, date_range_slider)
```

But how do I pass `layout` to `components` or `script` or `div`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just pass it like anything else:

```
script, div = components(layout)
```